# Kafka provided Zookeeper vs separate download

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am setting up kafka in production environment. I found that Kafka tar file comes with zookeeper. **What are the pros and cons of using zookeeper that is shipped with kafka vs a compatible version of zookeeper downloaded from apache zookeeper directly?**

What is recommended ?

Comment: Well, you may want to download Apache ZooKeeper separately. Keeping Kafka & ZooKeeper distribution separate makes things easier to understand. 

Assume you want to keep ZooKeeper on a separate server, in such case you do not want to put Kafka's distribution on ZooKeeper sever and use it for starting & stopping ZooKeeper.

Comment: @AshishBhosle Is there any harm in using the zookeeper distributed in kafka? AFAIK, Kafka's documentation does not mention anything specific.

Comment: Absolutely no harm